# Does changing the order of HTML with Javascript help SEO

Tags: seo

On my website, I have a booking widget at the top of each page to allow visitors to enter our booking engine. The code behind it uses quite a bit of HTML, pushing down the content on each page in the source. In an attempt to better my SEO, I decided to have the code placed in a DIV tag at the bottom of the page, and, when the DOM is ready, I use JQuery to physically move the DIV from the bottom of the DOM to the top where it needs to be to render correctly.

My question is if this is really helping SEO? Does Google look at the DOM/Source after all Javascript has run, or before? Does moving these few hundred lines of HTML to the bottom of the HTML source gain me any advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spiders do not process javascript. So any content that appears/moves or is created by javascript will appear as if it hasn't been moved or created at all.

Comment: I don't think this is, or at least will remain, a safe assumption. Google and others have done research into taking client-side scripting into account when indexing pages, because so much of "Web 2.0" became utterly inaccessible without Javascript. And while it makes good SEO sense to provide fallbacks, Google isn't likely to leave huge swaths of the web un-indexed.

Comment: @eyelidlessness, I agree. But then, all of SEO is pretty much a moving target, isn't it? I guess in the long run, the best you can do is to make content that's as semantically pure as you can as a sort of risk reduction measure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be really surprised if web crawlers execute the scripts on the page. They probably scan the raw response.

Answer (score 1):

That doesnot have any effect on the SEO.

But placing the javascript at the bottom will defnitely help you to load the webpages faster.

There is no harm for SEO as well, you can defnitely proceed with your approach

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between javascript executed on load versus during the user session. The on-load javascript is more times than not indexed by google. The dynamic content or alterations on the client side are not well indexed.
So, it can't be ignored.